# Does opening an fstream in fstream::out mode erase its current content ?

Tags: c++, file-io, fstream, eof

As the title says , does opening an `fstream` in `fstream::out` mode erase its current content ?
If no , what is the the best way to erase a .txt file using the `fstream` library .

And what is the equivalent of `EOF` in the C++ `fstream` library ?

Comment: According to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/open/: "`trunc` Any contents that existed in the file before it is open are discarded."

Comment: To answer the second question, `EOF` is the equivalent of `EOF`.  The equivalent of `feof` is `istream::eof` , note that it is equally wrong to use this in a loop condition in C++ as it is in C.

Comment: NB. Since you have two separate questions you should have posted two separate questions (or tried to post two separate questions anyway, I expect duplicates exist for both)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a `std::basic_filebuf` opens a file it acts as though it calls the relative C functions (whether it actually does so or not is up to the implementation).

The table in [filebuf.members] outlines what happens when certain flags are passed, if you only pass `std::ios_base::out` then it acts as though the file were opened with the stdio string `"w"`, which will erase your file if it already exists.

The default for `fstream` if no flags are passed is to call `basic_filebuf::open` with `std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out`, which acts as though `"r+"` were used, which in turn positions the file position at the start of the file, but leaves the contents intact if it already exists.

For reference:

[image]